# Minecraft crashing with message 'Game ended with bad state (exit code -1073740791)'

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I've been searching the internet for ages, I've tried reinstalling Minecraft, deleting Java and reinstalling that, even tried using earlier versions of Minecraft but nothing seems to work.

Here's what shows up when I try to launch the game

```
[13:53:39 INFO]: Job 'Version & Libraries' finished successfully (took 0:00:01.578)
[13:53:39 INFO]: Launching game
[13:53:39 INFO]: Unpacking natives to C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.11.2\1.11.2-natives-52547078805697
[13:53:39 INFO]: Launching in C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft
[13:53:39 INFO]: Half command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_25\bin\javaw.exe -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M -Dos.name=Windows 10 -Dos.version=10.0 -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.11.2\1.11.2-natives-52547078805697 -cp C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\netty\1.6\netty-1.6.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\oshi-project\oshi-core\1.1\oshi-core-1.1.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\jna\3.4.0\jna-3.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\platform\3.4.0\platform-3.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\ibm\icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\4.6\jopt-simple-4.6.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\io\netty\netty-all\4.0.23.Final\netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\17.0\guava-17.0.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.3.2\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.9\commons-codec-1.9.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.4\gson-2.2.4.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\authlib\1.5.24\authlib-1.5.24.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\realms\1.10.11\realms-1.10.11.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.8.1\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.3\httpclient-4.3.3.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\it\unimi\dsi\fastutil\7.0.12_mojang\fastutil-7.0.12_mojang.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.0-beta9\log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.0-beta9\log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.11.2\1.11.2.jar net.minecraft.client.main.Main
[13:53:39 INFO]: Looking for orphaned versions to clean up...
[13:53:40 INFO]: Looking for old natives & assets to clean up...
[13:53:48 ERROR]: Game ended with bad state (exit code -1073740791)
[13:53:48 INFO]: Ignoring visibility rule and showing launcher due to a game crash
[13:53:48 INFO]: Deleting C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.11.2\1.11.2-natives-52547078805697
[13:53:48 WARN]: Couldn't delete C:\Users\Adam Wolanyk\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.11.2\1.11.2-natives-52547078805697 - scheduling for deletion upon exit
```

Comment: Is this modded or vanilla?

Comment: This seems to be happening a lot recently with players. Do you have a nVidia graphics card? It appears that people who updated to the latest driver (released not too long ago) experience this issue. At least that's what I believe.

Answer (score 4):

Same issue: I have recently updated to Nvidia 378.49.

Research reveals that Nvidia is aware of the problem and is working on a fix. Mojang suggests:
https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-112780

I'm reverting to 376.33 because i didn't see an option to re-install 378.49 without the 3Dvision in the GeForce Experience app. I got the older version here: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx?lang=en-us

CONFIRMED: Minecraft is working now with 376.33!